# Using NSURLSession to POST, what is the correct way to post the variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service. Trying to set up a basic web service. Seems like the  tutorial is old material and ASIHTTPRequest is no longer continued. I have been trying to use NSURLRequest instead. First question, is NSURLRequest a pretty standard way to be doing this? I just want something for basic GET, POST etc, should I be doing it a different way?

My code is:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSLog(@"We want to unlock for the code %@",self.textField.text);

    //Get a device ID, (actually can't do this aymore)
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"My iPhone";
    NSString *code = self.textField.text;


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.madasd.co/promos/"]];

    request.HTTPMethod=@"POST";

    //Set the header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rw_app_id=1&code=%@&device_id=%@",code,uniqueIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
    NSData *requestBodyData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody=requestBodyData;

    //Create url and fire request

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [conn start];


    return TRUE;
}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{


    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);

}
```

Second question, I have tested the backend using curl so I know it works fine, however the response I get is "Invalid Request", I think this is because the string I am sending is not correct. Am I doing this correct using the var names and & operators? Any pointers on this would be great! thanks. (Running a LAMP server on Linode!)

EDIT:

Also tried sending as JSON:

```
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"rw_app_id",code,@"code",uniqueIdentifier,@"device_id", nil];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *requestBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
request.HTTPBody=requestBodyData;
```

Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Don't use `NSURLConnection`. It is deprecated as of iOS 9. Use `NSURLSession`. See [Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) in the *URL Loading System Programming Guide.*
2. Decide what type of request you need to prepare. You specified `application/xml` in your header, but are creating a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. Your `Content-Type` header must match how you're building the `HTTPBody`.

   What type of request does your server require? `x-www-form-urlencoded`? XML? JSON?

   Also, what type of response does your server provide?
3. If building a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request (as suggested by the body of your request), you are not properly percent escaping the values (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20398755/1271826).
4. If you use delegate based `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`, you should not just grab the results in `didReceiveData`. What you need to do is

   - Instantiate a `NSMutableData` before starting the request;
   - Have `didReceiveData` merely append to that `NSMutableData`;
   - Only when `connectionDidFinishLoading:` (in `NSURLConnection`) or `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` (in `NSURLSession`) is called, should you then use the `NSMutableData`.

   Alternatively, if using the block-based `NSURLSession`, this concern is completely eliminated (since you're not implementing any delegate methods). Using  `completionHandler`-based methods of `NSURLSession` is much easier.
5. If all of this is too complicated, you might consider using [AFNetworking's](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) `AFHTTPSessionManager` (but not `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`) to build your requests. It gets you out of the weeds of properly building requests, implementing delegate methods, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of that Rob, exactly what I was looking for. Yeah I read that AFNetworking may be the way to go. I'll try and give it a go the manual way first though. I'm running a LAMP on Linode, is there a way I can find out what the format of the requests should be?

Comment: It just depends upon how you write your web service (in PHP?). One of the easiest approaches is to have the server receive `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests (because you can just use `$_POST` and `$_GET`), but return JSON responses (to make it easier for the client app to parse the response). Another, not uncommon, design approach is to write web service that receives JSON requests and sends JSON responses (useful if the requests you're sending to the server are going to be complicated). Just decide on the desired interface and write server and client code accordingly.

Comment: Yeh it's in PHP. If it sends data back it uses JSON. I'm guessing sending the data in JSON format is the way to go.

Comment: The fact that it sends JSON responses doesn't mean you must send JSON requests. If the PHP does `json_decode` of the request, then, yes, send JSON request. But if you're using `$_POST` and `$_GET` and the like, then you're processing `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. So (a) figure out which type of request you're going to send; and (b) set the `Content-Type` header and format the `HTTPBody` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, in my PHP I'm accessing variables using $_POST. Okay so it's x-www-form-urlencoded. Must be a problem with my url.

Comment: Fixed it with [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap the strings into a dictionary and get the NSData object from a call to NSJSONSerialization. Though it depends on the form expected by the server.

Comment: I'm running a LAMP server on Linode